# Authentication with google auth , jwt token, django rest framework, nextj

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, google-authentication, social-authentication

How can I implement authentication system using Django Rest Framework backend and  Next js frontend  for google oauth (social auth) with jwt token ?